# My application will not show up in the Market on 4.0 devices

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I recently bought a Galaxy Nexus and flashed 4.0.4 onto it (I don't know if this affected the problem). My application used to, but no longer, is displayed in the Android Market on the device when searching for it or even when navigating to My Apps.

It does display in my launcher correctly once installed and runs perfectly, however it will not show up in the Android Market. I am very confused as to why this is (comes up on my Nexus One, Droid X, Galaxy S etc.) and my min SDK version is 7.

In my Manifest
uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what's the maxSdkVersion in AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 1):

Turn off the copy write protection and it will show up in a few hours..It's better to implement you're own authentication system.

Comment: Just one follow up question: is there any program that will automatically help me to create an authentication system?

Comment: There is no automatic program...but there are a few libraries that exist to make the task easier. Start your research [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen only on your device or on other GNs as well? You can use the developer console to find out what devices the app won't show up on. Find the 'Supported devices' section, then click 'Show devices' and do a search for 'Samsung'. If it is filtered, it might be due to the permissions/features you are using in the manifest. Check those and and `requried=false` as necessary (if possible).